# Javascript - passing percentage of variable to charts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, math

I am a total newbie to javascript and bascially i need to know how to make the following work

The original working code is

```
var initial_deposit = document.querySelector('#initial_deposit'),
```

But i want it to be the value + 25% of it (obviously not like the below but just to show the thought process)

```
var initial_deposit = document.querySelector('#initial_deposit' / 4 + '#initial_deposit'),
```

could anybody point me in the right direction or help me with the string syntax i need to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

When using document.querySelector

> The querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a
> specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

i will sugest to use document.getElementById().value and then do you calculation and change the value.

if you get the value as a string use parseInt()

Comment: even by changing to getElementByid from querySelector the resulting output is Uncaught TypeError: initial_deposit is null and that is without the caulction part added?

Comment: can you post the getElementById line? with value inside ()

Comment: var initial_deposit = document.getElementById('#initial_deposit'),

Comment: In document.getElementById() you need to look for the id of the field, not the CSS class so if your field is initial_deposit look for document.getElementById("initial_deposit") with out the # or . that symbols class in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what type of element `#initial_deposit` is, but assuming it's an input field:

1. Parse the value of `#initial_deposit`
2. Multiply it by 1.25 to increase it by 25%.

```
var value = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#initial_deposit').value);
var initial_deposit = value * 1.25;
```